# How to prepare 4-aminophenyl zinc iodide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I'm trying to follow a published synthetic procedure from *Direct preparation of new organozinc reagents, aminophenylzinc iodides, and their applications*:<sup>[1]</sup>

$$\ce{H2N-Ph-I + \underset{(Rieke)}{Zn} -> H2N-Ph-ZnI}$$

However, I can not manage to reproduce the results.
The Rieke zinc was prepared by lithium naphthalide and $\ce{ZnCl2}$.

<sup>[1]</sup> Jung, H.-S.; Kim, S.-H.; *Tetrahedron Lett.* **2015,** *56* (8), 1004–1006 (DOI: [10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.01.053](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.01.053)).

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: I didn't read the Tet Lett paper, but the point is - what are you having issues with? Extraction of product? Yield? Colour change not going as reported in the paper? NMR doesn't correspond to product? No change in TLC even after 7 days? Just saying "it's not working" is sorta like... going to the doctor and saying "I'm sick". You need to describe symptoms, otherwise the doctor can't try to give you anything useful.